# How to make jquery to php code?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make jquery code to php code. But i don't understand, my code structure is correct or not.

Here is jQuery code:

```
let params = {
    locale: 'en_US',
    client_country_code: 'US',
    fb_api_req_friendly_name: 'save_core_profile_info',
    access_token: token_user
};

params.work = JSON.stringify([{
    "id": 123456789,
    "privacy": '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
    "ref": "nux_android"
}]);
```

And here is my trying php code:

```
$params = array(
    "locale" => 'en_US',
    "client_country_code" => 'US',
    "fb_api_req_friendly_name" => 'save_core_profile_info',
    "access_token" => $token_user);

$params->work = json_encode(array(array(
    "id" => 12345678,
    "privacy" => '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
    "ref" => "nux_android"
    )));
```

If my php coding is not correct, how to i coding php code for making jQuery to php? thanks.

Comment: looks fine except for `token_user` as that looks like be another variable in javascript.

Comment: Since `$params` is an array you want `$params['work']`

Comment: What @AbraCadaver said, or you could cast the array into an object. `$params = (object) array(...)`

Comment: please update your answer with full code. thanks @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be a PHP array:

```
$params = array(
    "locale" => 'en_US',
    "client_country_code" => 'US',
    "fb_api_req_friendly_name" => 'save_core_profile_info',
    "access_token" => $token_user);

$params["work"] = json_encode(array(array(
    "id" => 12345678,
    "privacy" => '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
    "ref" => "nux_android"
    )));
```

If you want it to be a PHP object:

```
$params = (object)array(
    "locale" => 'en_US',
    "client_country_code" => 'US',
    "fb_api_req_friendly_name" => 'save_core_profile_info',
    "access_token" => $token_user);

$params->work = json_encode(array(array(
    "id" => 12345678,
    "privacy" => '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
    "ref" => "nux_android"
    )));
```

Comment: i am not tested your code, because i have another one problem.